# How to pause rxjava Observable.interval when underlying activity pauses

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-livedata

Im using MVVM architecture, my data layer / repositories are using RxJava but view model to view layer is using LiveData.

In my view model, I poll server using rxjava `Observable.interval`.

Currently my issue is that how to pause the polling when underlying view (fragment) goes to paused state?

Would it make things easier if I remove the rxjava to liveData conversion and observe rxjava directly on view?

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    private final MediatorLiveData<Resource<DataItem>> dataItems = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    MyViewModel(...) {
        disposables.add(Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // How to pause this?
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(n -> loadData())
                .subscribe());
    }

    void loadData() {
        disposables.add(dataRepository.getData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(__ -> dataItems.setValue(Resource.loading()))
                .subscribe(dataResp -> dataItems.setValue(Resource.success(dataResp)),
                        throwable -> dataItems.setValue(Resource.error(throwable))));
    }

    // This is observed by view 
    LiveData<Resource<DataItem>> getDataItems() {
        return dataItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call resume/stop from your controller, from your viewmodel change to :

```
...
private final Disposable poolingDisposable;
...

MyViewModel(...) {
    resumePooling()
}

public void resumePooling(){
    if(poolingDisposable == null){
        poolingDisposable = Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .doOnNext(n -> loadData())
           .subscribe();

        disposables.add(poolingDisposable)
    }
}

public void stopPooling(){
    if(poolingDisposable != null){
        poolingDisposable.dispose();
        poolingDisposable = null
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCleared(){
    disposables.dispose()
}
```

from your controller (if an activity or fragment)

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    viewModel.resumePooling();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    viewModel.stopPooling();
}
```